# Is this face topology good for animation?

Tags: topology

[image: Is the topology in this image good for animation. And can I move on to professional level with this kind of modeling]

Is the topology in this image good for animation. And can I move on to professional level with this kind of modeling

Comment: Counting 2 visible Ngons and 2 visible topological errors on quads and loops

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should avoid tris and ngons in your geometry, even if its a game model (its ok for mobile game models though - depends on polycount)

[image]

The meshflow is ok, its not good around the nostrils. Here is a good edgeflow that I recommend, its from a Zbrush course:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Zbrush workshop with Ryan Kingslien](http://blog.timothyeustace.com/2012/04/zbrush-workshops-with-ryan-kingslien.html)</sup> 
 <sup>Direct Source: [Workshops with Ryan Kingslien](https://www.uartsy.com/search/node/Ryan%20Kingslien)</sup> 
 <sup>Probably the Anatomy Of The Face (no guarantee)</sup>

You will know when you are ready for professional level, someone will just employ you. There are different levels among professionals too. Just practice and your confidence level will increase. You are basically ready when you know what you are doing.

Comment: Jerryno, could you please post a link to the Z-Brush course you've mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: @Gonzou I pulled this from my reference folder but I look it up.

Comment: Your answer is very encouraging. I'll do my best. Thanks.