# Tips for making the face topology

Tags: modeling, topology

I have been using blender for about a year now and so far I have the same problem with making a character. I can't seem to make a good face.
Here is what my faces look like.
[image]

[image]

i have been trying to make an anime model for a while but for some reason there is always a problem with the face.
is there any way i could make this look a little better?

Comment: I think this kind of forum may be more appropriate to have feedback on this kind of question : http://blenderartists.org/forum/. Also you may find references on this site http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?269376-Possible-Anime-Face-Topology-Reference&highlight=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***QUICK TIP:*** The proper edge flow of your mesh is the key to a good looking model. Your topology is bad- it doesn't define the head's shape well. 
Start from extruding the eyelid circular shape, then do the same with lips. Keep going further and then connect eyelid and lips meshes together. And remember to avoid ngons (you've got some there).
[image]

I hope you get the idea. Of course it's one of the topology variant. Type *'manga head topology'* in google graphics to see some different topology edge flows examples.
[image]

Comment: Also, see the picture under Jerryno 's answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26031/is-this-face-topology-good-for-animation